# Complex numbers $z$ and $w$ proof

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing

How should I go about proving the statement, $\forall w, z \in \mathbb{C}, |z+iw|=|z-iw|$ if and only if $z\bar w \in \mathbb{R}$?

I'm having some trouble understanding complex numbers. This reminds me of a conjugate, should I use the conjugate to multiply then for the forwards implication?

Comment: Welcome. Take squares and remember that $|z|^2=z \bar z$

Comment: Could you explain a bit? Should I make $z=w$ because $z+iw$ is not a complex number but a group of complex numbers

Comment: Regarding your last comment, saying that "$z+iw$ is not a complex number but a group of complex numbers" is like saying "$2+4*8$ is not an integer but a group of integers". The thing is, the integers are closed under multiplication and addition so $2+4*8$ is, indeed, an integer (it's equal to 34). And the complex numbers are closed under multiplication and addition so $z+iw$ is, indeed, a complex number (if you assign $z=5+6i$ and $w=7+8i$ then I'm sure you can compute $z+iw$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$|z+iw|^2-|z-iw|^2=(z+iw)\overline{(z+iw)} - (z-iw)\overline{(z-iw)}\\
=(z+iw)(\bar z - i \bar w)-(z-iw)(\bar z +i \bar w) = 2i(\bar z w-z \bar w) = 2i (\overline{z\bar w}-z\bar w)
$$

Therefore $$|z+iw| = |z-iw| \iff \overline{z\bar w} - z \bar w =0 \iff z \bar w \in \mathbb R. \blacksquare$$

Comment: awesome. this really is neat math